# How can I handle multiple values in a constructor's try-catch

Tags: kotlin, constructor, try-catch

I can handle a failing assignment in a constructor easily:

```
val v: BigDecimal

constructor(s: String) {
  v = try {
    BigDecimal(s)
  }
  catch (e: Exception) {
    BigDecimal.ZERO
  }
}
```

But how can I handle the case if I need to fill two variables? This doesn't work:

```
constructor(s: String) {
  (v, type) = try {
    Pair(BigDecimal(s), RealTypes.Normal)
  }
  catch (e: Exception) {
    Pair(BigDecimal.ZERO, RealTypes.NaN)
  }
}
```

Vals can only be assigned once, of course, although I'm not sure the constructor couldn't be an exception to this rule. But as it is, this isn't working, either, because of this rule:

```
constructor(value: String) {
  v = try {
    type = RealTypes.Normal
    BigDecimal(value, context)
  }
  catch (e: Exception) {
    type = RealTypes.NaN
    BigDecimal.ZERO
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
constructor(s: String) {
    val result = runCatching { BigDecimal(s) }
    v = result.getOrDefault(BigDecimal.ZERO)
    type = if (result.isSuccess) RealTypes.Normal else RealTypes.NaN
}
```

Or that?

```
constructor(s: String) {
    runCatching { BigDecimal(s) }.apply {
        v = getOrDefault(BigDecimal.ZERO)
        type = if (isSuccess) RealTypes.Normal else RealTypes.NaN
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that's what I call slick. Seems the winning one to me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found this approach to work but I don't like it that much.

```
constructor(s: String) {
  val (v, type) = try {
    Pair(BigDecimal(value), RealTypes.Normal)
  }
  catch (e: Exception) {
    Pair(BigDecimal.ZERO, RealTypes.NaN)
  }
  this.v = v;
  this.type = type;
}
```

Comment: intstead of using the plain `Pair` constructor you could use the `to` infix function: `BigDecimal(value) to RealTypes.Normal`

Comment: That's a nice one, although not exactly self documenting in this case. :-)

Comment: I think it is as obvious. "to" implies a mapping, which a Pair is. But again, it's a matter of taste. Using the plain constructor is completely correct too. :) But there's a catch: Using a Pair adds unecessary complexity to the solution a simple problem. Maybe that's why you don't like it as well.

Comment: But this isn't a mapping, actually. This is just a tuple, two values, not mapped to each other, just existing in parallel. Well, I still like the `to` approach and started to use in other, similar places. Infix just looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

What about using local variables, like this?

```
val bigDecimal: BigDecimal
val bigDecimalType: RealTypes

constructor (s: String) {
    var number: BigDecimal
    var type: TealTypes

    try {
        type = RealTypes.Normal
        number = BigDecimal(s)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        type = RealTypes.NaN
        number = BigDecimal.ZERO
    }
    bigDecimal = number
    bigDecimalType = type
}
```

Here `number` and `type` are constructor's local variables that would be assigned to `bigDecimal` and `bigDecimalType` val's.

Comment: Yes, I posted practically the same myself finally. But in the meantime, we have much more compact solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Val use lateinit var in the constructor class . This is sample example

```
class Myclass() {
lateinit var v: BigDecimal

constructor(s: String) : this() {
    v = try {
        BigDecimal(s)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        BigDecimal.ZERO
    }
}

fun print() {
    println(v)
}
}
```

then call like this

```
  Myclass("100").print()     //output is 100
```

Comment: The IDE greys out the `lateinit`, I wonder. Yes, I checked, it can be assigned later anywhere. I'm not sure this is the real solution. I actually found another one, but it isn't pretty: use the `Pair` approach to a temporary `var` in the constructor and assign it to the original `val`s. Ugly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to know whether the exception was thrown:

```
class Foo {
    val a: BigDecimal
    val b: RealTypes

    constructor(s: String) {
      var failed = false  

      a = try { 
          BigDecimal(s)
      } catch (e: NumberFormatException) { 
          failed = true
          BigDecimal.ONE
      }

      b = if(failed) RealTypes.NaN else RealTypes.Normal  
    }
}
```

This way you can use the expression notation first for the exception and then for the if-else-block which satifies the constraint that a `val` can only be initialized once.

Note: It is a good idea to catch specific exceptions if it is clear what the exception will be (in this case `NumberFormatException`).

Comment: There can be two exceptions, actually, (`ArithmeticException` is the other one) and in similar cases, sorry, I don't agree. I don't want to handle any exception specifically, just to know that the conversion didn't happen for any reason. I know that there is a trend to abhor plain Exceptions but I never subscribed to that trend in my life. In cases where it's logical, I'm perfectly at ease with plain Exceptions. :-)

Comment: @Gábor In case of the constructor which only takes one String there can only be one Exception, see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String). But otherwise, ok it might be a matter of taste. What do you think about the rest of the solution?

Comment: Being self-documenting for `Pair` vs. `to` is a good point. But for using specific exceptions it is too. Isn't it? :)

Comment: I use the other constructor that passes a context, just didn't think it necessary to include it here because it distracts from the actual issue at hand. Well, I don't know. I don't like either solution, neither yours nor mine, really. :-) I'd really say that a constructor should allow both assignments to a `val`, both in the `try` body and in the `catch` clause. Once out of the constructor, it's sealed for life, that's OK. But we should be able to use the basic logic to initialize them all. Of course, it works with single values, it's just a problem with multiple ones.